# How do I include the following html as a sting in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sl" clickcol>
<span ng-class="boolChangeClass?'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right':'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'"></span>
</button>
```

as you can see it has single and double quotations and I am confused about how I could include it in my javascript, since wrapping it in single or double quotes won't work, is concatenation the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an escape character - `\`

```
var x = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sl" clickcol>';
x = x + '<span ng-class="boolChangeClass?\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\':\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\'"></span>';
x = x + '</button>';
```

Edit - you can also create a single multiline string if you prefer:

```
var x = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sl" clickcol>\
<span ng-class="boolChangeClass?\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\':\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\'"></span>\
</button>';
```

Comment: no particular reason - just the style guideline on the codebase I'm working on at the moment, so I'm in the habit of it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to write DOM with JS is to use single quotes for your own strings.  In the case where you encounter more single quotes you can escape them with the backslash character.

```
var html = '<button class="btn primary">Matt\'s Button</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape things in JavaScript with a backslash. You can have:

```
var x = "\"Hello,\" said the milkman.";
```

And your string will contain double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape quotations that are equal to the ones used for surrounding your code:

```
alert("This is a \" test");
```

The `\` is not included.

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5xVj/)

Answer (score 0):

Just escape your quotes and erase the newlines:

```
var str = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sl" clickcol><span ng-class="boolChangeClass?\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\':\'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\'"></span></button>';
```